# I recently have gotten into python and can't import anything

Tags: python-3.x

I'm a beginner in python and keep running into the problem of not being able to import literally anything. I have searched everywhere to find others that have had this problem but I can't find a solution to it.

I've tried with adding python to the PATH variables and have followed many tutorials on the issue.

```
import info

print(info)
```

This is a simple import function to print something off of a text file but I keep getting the `ModuleNotFoundError`

Comment: Is that "info" a file or not? Because you cannot make your own modules unless its a file or a real module(e.g. math). you can rename modules by the keyword "as" instead

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `import` is for loading code, so unless you have a module/library called "info" that you are trying to load, this wouldn't really do anything except fail they way that it did for you…

Comment: You can find tutorials at http://python.org or via a web search using your favorite search engine.

Comment: @dtanabe Sorry, I have no idea how to use this site yet. Info is just a random text file with a few words on it

Comment: post your code snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`import` is for importing code modules. To read a file and print it out would be something like:

```
f = open('somefile.txt','r')
print(f.read())
```

I would strongly suggest reading/watching a tutorial.